# Usage of “nohow”

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to use ***nohow*** this way? Like there is no way I would even thought about it.

> I ***nohow*** thought that it would happen
> I ***nohow*** thought that you would come
> I ***nohow*** thought that she would say that

Comment: "no how" is slang and sub-standard. And it is written separately anyway. The proper term is no way. What research did you do here?

Comment: The dictionary (vial google) says "*In uneducated speech* to emphasise a negative." Do you want to appear uneducated?

Comment: [It is not usually written separately.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nohow)

Answer (score 1):

It is very colloquial and is used idiomatically in contexts like this:

> A sumo wrestler from Japan just ran a three-minute mile!
>
> -- Nohow. No way.

It could be paraphrased as "under no circumstances whatsoever".

When used alone in that manner it means, emphatically, "I do not believe what you just said. That can not be  possible."

See [these examples](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=10e9cf505b4d02e6&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&sxsrf=ACQVn09g9Wqjuis39CL8k37uKE4v_iAdIA:1711397799509&q=%22nohow.%20No%20way%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivsnmbtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibtqLPnZCFAxXNk4kEHVdeBfMQ0pQJegQIWRAB&biw=1246&bih=638&dpr=1).

P.S.  When used as it is in the original question, it would be substandard and a mark of a lack of education. But anyone might use it as I show in the example here, regardless of their education level. It is an intentional code-shifting of a sort, as when a person who normally speaks grammatically says "ain't gonna happen" to mean "My answer is final: I'm not going to do it".